# upgrade freezes, leaves system un-bootable

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

After the previous upgrades (from 12.10 via 13.04 to 13.10) went without problems, I tried to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.

After downloading it stopped and asked for stopping xscreensaver, I did. Then there were several error messages concerning fontconfig "...out of memory". At one of these error messages the system froze, not even the mouse pointer was moving anymore, nor ctrl-alt F2 was working.

After hardware reset, at boot the system complained about not being able to identify the hardware and only showed a box "what do you want to do".
What can I do? Does an install from CD make sense? And which one, 13.10 or 14.04?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the dialog box said?

Comment: first a message shows up to tell that the graphic system is in low resolution mode, then a box says that the hardware could not be identified. After confirming the ok button, another box shows up ("what do you want to do") where a text can be typed in. I typed "restart" and hit esc several times, and the system rebooted to the same.

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is better to try a fresh install of 14.04 from a DVD or Live USB drive. After booting to ubuntu 14.04 from DVD dont forget to backup your files in the home directory.

I recomment 14.04 because it is an LTS. Much more error free, fast and also a way better in performance than 13.10.

Here is some instructions [after Installing Ubuntu 14.04](http://smashingweb.info/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-for-perfect-desktop/)

Comment: well, I downloaded the DVD, started it, and it gave me the option to re-install 14.04, which I did. The step of re-installing the packages stopped for 2 hours at 95%, then the system asked for restart. 14.04 came up. Now checking what has been installed and what not.  
Not a really nice experience. I'll wait with upgrading other PCs.

Answer (score 0):

I first downloaded a copy of 14.04 LTS. Made a bootable USB with this. Tried it on my computer with 13.10. It worked fine in all aspects, including auto-configuring of internet. Then I opened 'Software Updater' and followed it. The upgrade was seamless with all my apps, including ppa-s, but except Google Earth.

I suggest you take backup of all data. Write a bootable DVD of 14.04 LTS. Install afresh. Wish you all the best.